# Looping through array of objects and storing it on a table[JS]

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop through an array of objects and store it on the table, Here is the sequence of events my code is doing.

1. Grab values from a JSON file [done]
2. Store them in my code as array of objects like so[done]:
   var results =
   {name : [], goals: [], assists: [] , team: []};

3.Display the content in a table where I want the format to be below:

```
     Name               Goals             Assists            Team
  Player 1 Name   Player 1 Goals     Player 1 Assists      Player 1 Team
```

4. Picked up object containing arrays looks like so:

```js
{
  assists: [4, 2, 2, 9, 1, 7, 3, 6, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2, 7, 3, 1, 18, 3, 10, 9],
  goals: [23, 20, 19, 19, 17, 16, 16, 16, 15, 15, 14, 13, 13, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10],
  name: ['J. Vardy', 'P. Aubameyang', 'D. Ings', 'Mohamed Salah', 'R. Sterlin', 'S. Mané ', 'S. Agüero', , , , , , , , , , , ,],
  team: ['Leicester', 'Arsenal', 'Southampton', 'Liverpool', 'Manchester City', 'Liverpool', 'Manchester City', , , , , , , , , , , ,],
}
```

5. My code sample obtain this is using the for each functionality as below but my results display nothing, Full code below: [in progress]

```
var stats, table;
var results = 
{name : [], goals: [], assists: [] , team: []};


//We need to initiate a request to read the json file
    $.getJSON('data/topscores.json')
     .done(function(data){ // Once done do the below



  $.each(data, function(keyIndex) { //Loop through the JSon, grab all values and store in obj array
        results.name[keyIndex] = (data[keyIndex].player.name)
        stats = data[keyIndex].statistics
        results.goals[keyIndex] = (stats[0].goals.total)
        results.assists[keyIndex] = (stats[0].goals.assists)
        results.team[keyIndex] = (stats[0].team.name)
        });

    table =  document.getElementById('rank').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]  //Grabbing first contents of table body

    for (var key in results.name.length) {
            var row = document.createElement('tr'); //insert 20 rows beginning of the loop
                Object.values(res).forEach(text => {  //Loop through object array and store values in respective table cells
                   var cell = document.createElement('td')
                   var textNode = document.createTextNode(text)
                   cell.appendChild(textNode)
                   row.appendChild(cell)
                });
                table.appendChild(row)
        }

}) //End of JSON function
```

Any help would be appreciated on how i can display the results array of objects into my table cells

Comment: Your code block is very unclear. Either describe the values/functions in detail, or (I think recommended) post some more of your code, so it would be self-explanatory.

Comment: hi k-wasilewski, thanks for the feedback. I have just updated the post to display the full code... basically my issue is displaying the content i grabbed from the json to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an element `<table></table>` and an object `data` containing your game data, you can display it in the table like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <table></table>
    <script>
      const data = {
        assists: [4, 2, 2, 9, 1, 7, 3, 6, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2, 7, 3, 1, 18, 3, 10, 9],
        goals: [23, 20, 19, 19, 17, 16, 16, 16, 15, 15, 14, 13, 13, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10],
        name: ['J. Vardy', 'P. Aubameyang', 'D. Ings', 'Mohamed Salah', 'R. Sterlin', 'S. Mané ', 'S. Agüero', , , , , , , , , , , ,],
        team: ['Leicester', 'Arsenal', 'Southampton', 'Liverpool', 'Manchester City', 'Liverpool', 'Manchester City', , , , , , , , , , , ,],
      };

      const titles = ['name', 'goals', 'assists', 'team'];

      const createElement = document.createElement.bind(document);
      const querySelector = document.querySelector.bind(document);

      const table = querySelector('table');
      const titleTr = createElement('tr');
      table.append(titleTr);

      titles.forEach(title => {
        const th = createElement('th');
        th.textContent = title.replace(/\w/, l => l.toUpperCase());
        titleTr.append(th);
      });

      Object.keys(Object.values(data)[0]).forEach(i => {
        const tr = createElement('tr');
        titles.forEach(title => {
          const td = createElement('td');
          td.textContent = data[title][i];
          tr.append(td);
        });

        table.append(tr);
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The obcious issue I see is your iteration over json results. The `for-in` loop is for iterating over object's properties only and you want to iterate over an array `results.name`.

Even if you were iterating over an object, your for loop syntax doesn't make much sense (iterating over array's length?!).

Try it like this: `for (let i=0; i<results.name.length; i++)`.

Also, what is `res` in `Object.values(res)`?!

Comment: I was trying to loop through the object array , res is just a short variable passover for results object array